# Java selenium getPageSource() doesen't return full page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get the html code from a page.
The page has javascript, but if I try to disable it in my broswer I see in the HTML source code that the elements I'm searching exists (but there are not in the String that I get in return from Selenium)
I tried also doing a GET request with postman and the html that I get back is correct (and also different from the one I get from Selenium)

When running the code, Selenium succesful opens the broswer and show me the page, if I do f12 and copy the html, the html code is corrected, but if I try to get it from the code with driver.getSourcePage() the string i get back is not correct.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
           // options.addArguments("--headless=new");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            driver.get(link);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            WebElement acceptButton = driver.findElement(By.className("cookie-alert-extended-button"));
            acceptButton.click();
            System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Everything works fine, even the accept cookie button, but on the System.out.println the html page that I get doesen't have the thing I need
(The page is fully loaded, because between the time of thread sleep if I copy the html code before the cookie button is clicked, I can see that the html code is full and correct, but when the code resume and the button is clicked, if I check my console the html code that I get is not correct.

VERSION OF MY CHROME: 114.0.5735.110

VERSION OF CHROMEDRIVER: 114.0.5735.90 (the latest avaiable on the chromedriver website)

Website I'm trying to get: https://www.lidl.it/c/le-offerte-per-la-tua-spesa/a10019307?tabCode=Current_Sales_Week
(the products that are in sales)

Comment: First of all it sounds like you didn't tried to debug it. sec, share with us the website link if you can.

Comment: @I.sh. I updated the post with the link